# Binding a class to the Container

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Suppose I have the following class:

```
class MyClass {

    private $someVar;

    public function __construct($someParameter) {
        $this->someVar = $someParameter;
    }

    public function display(){
        return "This is the variable value " . $this->someVar;
    }

}
```

How am I suppose to bind this class to the container as I need to pass the variable to the constructor as well?

Normally, I would get an instance of the class and pass the variable. Like;

```
$param = 'this is my variable.';
$obj = new MyClass($param);
echo $obj->display();
```

I need to do this through the service provider.

Comment: You can use this syntax `$this->app->when('App\Http\Controllers\MyClass')
          ->needs('$variableName')
          ->give($value);`

Comment: @Maraboc from where will i get the `$value`?

Comment: It depends on your case, with this you will give it the same value every time !!

Comment: @Maraboc Like how can I give the value `MyClass::display()`??